# #1451 - Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails

Tags: mysql

Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться, как работают связи в таблицах.

Имею в базе test две таблицы InnoDB: table1 и table2. Таблица table2 имеет Foreign Key атрибут fk, он указывает на table1.id.

Дамп базы: http://pastebin.com/JbCjpVpC

Хочу: чтобы при обновлении записи в родительской таблицы (table1) запись обновлялась в дочерней (table2), а при удалении записи из родительской таблицы - с дочерней ничего не происходило.

Зачем хочу: чтобы при удалении данных из table1, данные из table2 оставались и по их FK их можно было идентифицировать. Настройки FK в дочерней таблице: `ON UPDATE: cascade, ON DELETE: no action`.

Если в дочерней таблице есть записи, которые ссылаются на записи в родительской таблице, я пытаюсь удалить кортеж в родительской таблице, то происходит ошибка:

```
DELETE FROM `test`.`table1` WHERE `table1`.`id` =1

MySQL said: Documentation
#1451 - Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`test`.`table2`, CONSTRAINT `table2_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`fk`) REFERENCES `table1` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE CASCADE)
```

Comment: Только если не объявлять ключ как внешний на уровне констрейнтов и поддерживать целостность прогаммно.

Comment: Судя по документации `on delete no action` тоже самое, что и `on delete restrict`, что и не дает Вам удалить родительскую запись пока есть дочерняя. На уровне `foreign key` все, что вы можете - это сделать `on delete SET NULL`, что соответственно проставит `null` в колонку `fk` соответствующих записей. Но и смысла сохранять какое-то значение в `fk`, когда удаляется родительская запись, тоже мало т.к. это значение будет больше ни к чему не привязанным.

Comment: В дампе по ссылке нет `table1`

Comment: все эти хорошие, логичные правила по обеспечению ссылочной целостности можно не ломать. Просто не удалять записи из table1, а помечать как удаленные (а совсем удалять, вместе с подчиненными записями - уже когда точно понятно, что это стало мусором, например через 50 лет)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Думаю, мой комент к вопросу можно посчитать ответом, переношу его сюда ) :

Правила по обеспечению ссылочной целостности можно не ломать. Просто не удалять записи из `table1`, а помечать как удаленные (а совсем удалять, вместе с подчиненными записями - уже когда точно понятно, что это стало мусором, например через 50 лет)